# Node.js connection with socket.io not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Hey guys that's one of my first time using node.js and socket.io so i will try to be clear as possible. So i am doing a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jkkd2Ohte8&t=220s) for a chat. 
And i don't know why the connection is not working when i am running my html page :

> http://localhost:8000/user/tchat (Symfony project)

I don't have the

> console.log('New user'); (i run the server with "node server.js")

But when i am going to :

> http://localhost:1337/

i have the

> console.log('This is a test');

I have 2 js files and one html page :

Server.js :

```
var http = require('http');

httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('This is a test');
    res.end('Hello World');
});

httpServer.listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('New user');
});
```

Client.js :

```
 (function($){

     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

})(jquery);
```

And the scripts of the html page :

```
<script src="http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="../js/js/client.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works fine for me, did you check the console for messages? I had to remove the `jquery` thing at the end of `Client.js` to make it work.

Comment: work for me removing the jquery thx a lot :)